# Redux Saga difference between all([...effects]) and all(effects)

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

i want to know what the difference between `all([...effects])` and `all(effects)`

there is notes for `all(effects)` in api but i didn't get it

> Notes
> When running Effects in parallel, the middleware suspends the Generator >until one of the following occurs:
>
> All the Effects completed with success: resumes the Generator with an >array containing the results of all Effects.
>
> One of the Effects was rejected before all the effects complete: throws >the rejection error inside the Generator.

Comment: Is there a typo in your question or title? You mention `all(effects)` in the title, but in the question, you're asking about `call`

Comment: @CoryDanielson i fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you've used promises before, running `all([call(effect1), call(effect2), call(effect3)])` is similar [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [jQuery's $.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

In the docs for all, there are 2 syntaxes, the only difference is that they return an array of results or an object of results.

- `all([effectA, effectB])`: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/docs/api#alleffects---parallel-effects
- `all({ a: effectA, b: effectB })`: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/docs/api#alleffects

When you use either syntax, redux-saga will run each effect in parallel, when they've all completed it will return the results in an array or object form.

```js
// all([...effects]) - returns an array of results
const [customers, products] = yield all([
    call(fetchCustomers),
    call(fetchProducts)
])

// all({ a: effectA, b: effectB }) - returns an object of results
const { customers, products } = yield all({
    customers: call(fetchCustomers),
    products: call(fetchProducts)
})
```

In both of these examples, redux saga will run fetchCustomers and fetchProducts immediately, and when both of them have completed, it will return the result back to your saga.

If any of the effects fails or throws an error, redux-saga will throw that error back into your saga/generator, and you'll have to handle that with a `try/catch`

---

Running the effects in parallel looks like this, compared to running them sequentially

```
// parallel
1. run effect A
2. run effect B
3. wait for responses... (imagine this takes 1 second)
4. get result B
5. get result A
6. continue saga
```

```
// sequentially
1. run effect A
2. wait for response.... (imagine this takes 1 second)
3. get result A
4. run effect B
5. wait for response... (wait another second)
6. get result B
7. continue saga
```